# grep excluding first char

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

How do I find a line where a pattern is in middle of line. i.e. in the following example. I want to only get 8th line but exclude 1st and 5th line grepping "@"

I know i would use `grep "^@"` to find only in first character but how to exclude it?

```
@DD65WKN1:203:H7T67ADXX:2:2216:19936:100494 1:N:0:
GTCGTTCTTCAGGTTCTC
+
FFFFFIIIIFFFIFFFFF
@DD65WKN1:203:H7T67ADXX:2:2216:6629:100501 1:N:0:
TAAAGTAGCAAAAATG
+
FFFFFFFFIFBFIFFF@DD65WKN1:203:H7T67ADXX:2:2216:6629:100501 1:N:0:
TAAAGTAGCAAAAATG
+
FFFFFFFFIFBFIFFF
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a FastQ file. Is the 8th line that you want to match correct? If it is then you might have a formatting problem in your file.

Comment: @PedroA, yes it is. Seems like there is some formatting problem with combining multiple file and wanted to see those lines with potential problems.

Comment: I don't think that you should only be matching "@" in the quality field because "@" is a valid quality character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match any character beforehand, so that `@` won't be matched if just in the first position:

```
$ grep '.@' file
FFFFFFFFIFBFIFFF@DD65WKN1:203:H7T67ADXX:2:2216:6629:100501 1:N:0:
```

Note that `.` matches any character. To be completely sure (first solution would match a line starting with `@@`), you can negate `@` by using:

```
grep '[^@]@' file
```

Or also indicate that you want to find any line starting with a no-@ set of characters (at least one, as indicated by `+`).

```
grep '^[^@]\+@' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use grep with `Perl-regex` option which supports negative lookbehind.

```
$ grep -P '(?<!^)@' file
FFFFFFFFIFBFIFFF@DD65WKN1:203:H7T67ADXX:2:2216:6629:100501 1:N:0:
```

The above grep command will print the line which doesn't have `@` symbol at the begining but it may present anwhere on that line.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing about unix filters is combining them

```
grep --invert-match '^@' file | grep '@'
```

or more traditionally

```
sed '/^@/d' file | grep '@'
```